# Android Left sliding menu bar

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, android-5.0-lollipop

Hi I am looking for the sliding menu similar to the below availble in iOS, I am looking similar in android, Is there any reference code available similar to this.

https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController/raw/master/Demo.gif

[image: similar pic]

Comment: please check this one https://github.com/ErNaveen/FacebookLikeNavigetion

Comment: see this link you will get solution http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-sidebar-navigation-drawer-with-icons/

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make use of this library by jfeinstein10: 
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
The drawer slides in/out very similar as in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is DrawerLayout in android. Just try this [tutorial](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/02/android-navigation-drawer-example.html). For more details, you can read this [document](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

In the case you need a root layout in DrawerLayout instead of ListView.
For example in my case:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f4f4f4" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#fff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_word"
            android:text="New words"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

now, on your activiy class:

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
TextView tv_word = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.tv_word );
tv_word.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearLayout);//don't forget it
        //.....
    }
});
```